# Show an image from storage Laravel5.5

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5.5

This is how i'm storing the image

```
if ($request->hasFile('photo')) {
$request->file('photo')->store('public/images');
$filename = $request->file('photo')->hashName();
$authUser = Auth::user();
Auth::user()->photoUrl = $filename;
$authUser->likes=0;
$authUser->save();
}
```

i already did a `php artisan storage:links`,file is in the storage/app/images folder also the filename stored in the database but i still cannot get the image when doing `<img src="{{ asset('public/images/' . $user->photoUrl) }}">`

its telling me:

> Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```html
<td><img height='' src="{{ url('images/' . \App\Photo::find($user->yourPhoto_id)->photo) }}" alt=""></td>
```

@Ayèch Hamza did you try it?